# The cryptic treasure hunt

Tags: cipher

I created this puzzle. This may be really challenging. But I assure you that there is a solid logic behind. (Note: Questions are cryptic)

## 1: Ucbemfol.jcancyf

[image]

## 2: Mwamebyr;assdpwhbporcrof;

[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zl8qkB3446jo5bjHvYy5vDnc2BLENmYu/view?usp=sharing)

## 3: TrpewylRam

[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4DFOJKPMVMIZhXurC-pYT13RNYiEdsm/view?usp=sharing)

## 4: Whagurghfiycaguykytghfgpfarlpf?

Hint 1:

> Question is cryptic

Hint 2:

> Be aware of everything you see

Hint 3: (Cryptic)

> ◢□▔◢□▷◢□▯◢■■◢□▲◢□▯◢□□◢□▤◢□△◢■■◢□▤◢□▩◢□▶◢□▥◢□▲◢□▧◢□▥◢□▤◢■■◢□▩◢□▮◢■■◢□□◢■■◢□▹◢□▥◢□▬◢□▬◢□▯◢□▷◢■■◢□▷◢□▯◢□▯◢□▤◢■▬◢■▊◢□▁◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□△◢□▯◢□▲◢□▲◢□▹◢■■◢□▉◢■■◢□▣◢□▯◢□▵◢□▬◢□▤◢■■◢□▮◢□▯◢□▴◢■■◢□▴◢□▲◢□□◢□▶◢□▥◢□▬◢■■◢□▢◢□▯◢□▴◢□▨◢■▊◢□▁◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□▢◢□▥◢■■◢□▯◢□▮◢□▥◢■■◢□▴◢□▲◢□□◢□▶◢□▥◢□▬◢□▥◢□▲◢■▬◢■■◢□▬◢□▯◢□▮◢□▧◢■■◢□▉◢■■◢□△◢□▴◢□▯◢□▯◢□▤◢■▊◢□▁◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□▬◢□▯◢□▯◢□▫◢□▥◢□▤◢■■◢□▤◢□▯◢□▷◢□▮◢■■◢□▯◢□▮◢□▥◢■■◢□□◢□△◢■■◢□▦◢□□◢□▲◢■■◢□□◢□△◢■■◢□▉◢■■◢□▣◢□▯◢□▵◢□▬◢□▤◢■▊◢□▔◢□▯◢■■◢□▷◢□▨◢□▥◢□▲◢□▥◢■■◢□▩◢□▴◢■■◢□▢◢□▥◢□▮◢□▴◢■■◢□▩◢□▮◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□▵◢□▮◢□▤◢□▥◢□▲◢□▧◢□▲◢□▯◢□▷◢□▴◢□▨◢■▻◢■▊◢■▊◢□▔◢□▨◢□▥◢□▮◢■■◢□▴◢□▯◢□▯◢□▫◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□▯◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢□▲◢■▬◢■■◢□□◢□△◢■■◢□▪◢□▵◢□△◢□▴◢■■◢□□◢□△◢■■◢□▦◢□□◢□▩◢□▲◢■▬◢■▊◢□▁◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□▨◢□□◢□▶◢□▩◢□▮◢□▧◢■■◢□▰◢□▥◢□▲◢□▨◢□□◢□▰◢□△◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□▢◢□▥◢□▴◢□▴◢□▥◢□▲◢■■◢□▣◢□▬◢□□◢□▩◢□▭◢■▬◢■▊◢□▂◢□▥◢□▣◢□□◢□▵◢□△◢□▥◢■■◢□▩◢□▴◢■■◢□▷◢□□◢□△◢■■◢□▧◢□▲◢□□◢□△◢□△◢□▹◢■■◢□□◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□▷◢□□◢□▮◢□▴◢□▥◢□▤◢■■◢□▷◢□▥◢□□◢□▲◢■▻◢■▊◢□▔◢□▨◢□▯◢□▵◢□▧◢□▨◢■■◢□□◢□△◢■■◢□▦◢□▯◢□▲◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□□◢□▴◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□▰◢□□◢□△◢□△◢□▩◢□▮◢□▧◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢□▲◢□▥◢■▊◢□█◢□□◢□▤◢■■◢□▷◢□▯◢□▲◢□▮◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢□▭◢■■◢□▲◢□▥◢□□◢□▬◢□▬◢□▹◢■■◢□□◢□▢◢□▯◢□▵◢□▴◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□△◢□□◢□▭◢□▥◢■▬◢■▊◢■▊◢□▁◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□▢◢□▯◢□▴◢□▨◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□□◢□▴◢■■◢□▭◢□▯◢□▲◢□▮◢□▩◢□▮◢□▧◢■■◢□▥◢□▱◢□▵◢□□◢□▬◢□▬◢□▹◢■■◢□▬◢□□◢□▹◢■▊◢□▉◢□▮◢■■◢□▬◢□▥◢□□◢□▶◢□▥◢□△◢■■◢□▮◢□▯◢■■◢□△◢□▴◢□▥◢□▰◢■■◢□▨◢□□◢□▤◢■■◢□▴◢□▲◢□▯◢□▤◢□▤◢□▥◢□▮◢■■◢□▢◢□▬◢□□◢□▣◢□▫◢■▮◢■▊◢□▏◢□▨◢■▬◢■■◢□▉◢■■◢□▫◢□▥◢□▰◢□▴◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□▦◢□▩◢□▲◢□△◢□▴◢■■◢□▦◢□▯◢□▲◢■■◢□□◢□▮◢□▯◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢□▲◢■■◢□▤◢□□◢□▹◢■□◢■▊◢□▙◢□▥◢□▴◢■■◢□▫◢□▮◢□▯◢□▷◢□▩◢□▮◢□▧◢■■◢□▨◢□▯◢□▷◢■■◢□▷◢□□◢□▹◢■■◢□▬◢□▥◢□□◢□▤◢□△◢■■◢□▯◢□▮◢■■◢□▴◢□▯◢■■◢□▷◢□□◢□▹◢■▬◢■▊◢□▉◢■■◢□▤◢□▯◢□▵◢□▢◢□▴◢□▥◢□▤◢■■◢□▩◢□▦◢■■◢□▉◢■■◢□△◢□▨◢□▯◢□▵◢□▬◢□▤◢■■◢□▥◢□▶◢□▥◢□▲◢■■◢□▣◢□▯◢□▭◢□▥◢■■◢□▢◢□□◢□▣◢□▫◢■▮◢■▊◢■▊◢□▉◢■■◢□△◢□▨◢□□◢□▬◢□▬◢■■◢□▢◢□▥◢■■◢□▴◢□▥◢□▬◢□▬◢□▩◢□▮◢□▧◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▩◢□△◢■■◢□▷◢□▩◢□▴◢□▨◢■■◢□□◢■■◢□△◢□▩◢□▧◢□▨◢■▊◢□▓◢□▯◢□▭◢□▥◢□▷◢□▨◢□▥◢□▲◢□▥◢■■◢□□◢□▧◢□▥◢□△◢■■◢□□◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□□◢□▧◢□▥◢□△◢■■◢□▨◢□▥◢□▮◢□▣◢□▥◢■►◢■▊◢□▔◢□▷◢□▯◢■■◢□▲◢□▯◢□□◢□▤◢□△◢■■◢□▤◢□▩◢□▶◢□▥◢□▲◢□▧◢□▥◢□▤◢■■◢□▩◢□▮◢■■◢□□◢■■◢□▷◢□▯◢□▯◢□▤◢■▬◢■■◢□□◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□▉◢▣▢◢▢▀◢▢▔◢■▊◢□▉◢■■◢□▴◢□▯◢□▯◢□▫◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□▯◢□▮◢□▥◢■■◢□▬◢□▥◢□△◢□△◢■■◢□▴◢□▲◢□□◢□▶◢□▥◢□▬◢□▥◢□▤◢■■◢□▢◢□▹◢■▬◢■▊◢□▁◢□▮◢□▤◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□□◢□▴◢■■◢□▨◢□□◢□△◢■■◢□▭◢□□◢□▤◢□▥◢■■◢□□◢□▬◢□▬◢■■◢□▴◢□▨◢□▥◢■■◢□▤◢□▩◢□▦◢□▦◢□▥◢□▲◢□▥◢□▮◢□▣◢□▥◢■▮

Comment: "cryptic clues" has a specific meaning here: it's a certain type of crossword clue that involves reparsing a sentence as definition and wordplay. Are you sure the [cryptic-clues] tag applies here?

Comment: By cryptic-clues, I didn't mean the crossword. I just pointed to the general cryptographic methods. I changed it to cipher now.

Comment: Beginning of an (obviously incomplete) answer, in rot13: gur svefg cat unf n fgrtnabtencuvpnyyl uvqqra zrffntr. Vg vf rnfl gb erirny ivn "mfgrt -n svyr". Gur grkg: "Uv! Lbh unir sbhaq gur uvqqra gernfher, zl urneg naq zl fcrpvnyvgl. V ernyyl qba'g bcra zlfrys gb crbcyr. Ohg lbh unir tbggra vagb zr qrrc. Lbh jvyy abj erprvir gur orfg bs rirelguvat lbh jvfu. Jvgu ybir <3"

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate rot13(Terng. Lbh ner irel pybfr gb svaqvat gur svefg bar. Gur punenpgrevfgvpf bs gur bar lbh sbhaq znl or urycshy.)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate, did you find what "1: Ucbemfol.jcancyf" meant?

Comment: @JohnBrookfields No (I almost haven't tried, in fact).

Comment: Ok, @mypronounismonicareinstate. Look the Hint 2 carefully. It is really a great hint.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate, have you tried this again?

Comment: I have been visiting this page to check for any new hints or useful comments, but I couldn't really think of anything else to try. I haven't noticed anything special about the seemingly random letters before the file links or about the hidden message I found. I found some obvious patterns in the 3rd hint that I haven't mentioned in the comments, but I don't feel like they get me any closer to converting it into readable text.

Comment: rot13(Gur guveq uvag qrpvcuref gb gur pbzcyrgr grkg bs *Gur Ebnq Abg Gnxra* ol Eboreg Sebfg.)